# How to understand "primitive types are Sync" in rust?

Tags: rust

I am reading https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-04-extensible-concurrency-sync-and-send.html

It says

> In other words, any type `T` is `Sync` if `&T` (an immutable reference to `T`) is `Send`, meaning the reference can be sent safely to another thread. Similar to `Send`, primitive types are `Sync`

How to understand this? If primitive types are `Sync`, so integer such as `i32` is `Sync`. Thus `&i32` can be sent safely to another thread. But I don't think so. I don't think a number reference in main thread can be send to another thread.

Comment: "A number variable has to be moved to a thread by reading the book (contradiction)" — ???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're confusing the concept of thread-safety with the concept of lifetime.

You are correct in that a reference to a value owned by `main()` can't be sent to a spawned thread:

```
// No-op function that statically proves we have an &i32.
fn opaque(_: &i32) {}

fn main() {
    let x = 0i32;
    std::thread::spawn(|| opaque(&x)); // E0373
}
```

This doesn't fail because `&x` is not `Send` (it is), but because `std::thread::spawn()` requires that the closure is `'static`, and it isn't if it captures a reference to something that doesn't have static lifetime.  The compiler gives us this hint along with the error:

```
note: function requires argument type to outlive `'static`
```

We can prove this by obtaining a reference with static lifetime (`&'static i32`) and sending it to a thread, which does work:

```
fn opaque(_: &i32) {}

fn main() {
    static X: i32 = 0;
    std::thread::spawn(|| opaque(&X));
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `opaque(&x)` and `opaque(&X)`? Otherwise, it will report `mismatched types` error.

Comment: @sgon00 Yes, I had a version where that wasn't required but simplified it, and in so doing made the explicit borrow necessary (and forgot to add it). Fixed.